# Format byte as a two character hex number

Tags: java

I would like to format byte as a two character hex number. In C# you would do this:

```
string.Format("{0:X2}", recvBuff[indx])
```

How do you do the same thing in Java?

Comment: The answer is probably `String.format("%02X", recvBuff[indx])` but opinions are still welcome.

Comment: Why don't you try and test, if you have an assumption?

Comment: Of course, I have tried. I just want to know if there are more correct ways to do this in Java.

Comment: Always 2 char? ie you want a leading zero for small values?

Answer (score 0):

The toString-method of Integer and Long can take a base, up to 36 afaik, so you would pick 16:

```
String hex = Integer.toString (recvBuff[indx], 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your question asks for a "two character", you will have to make sure values are not greater than 256 (otherwise will print 3 hex digits or more).  You also need to pad with zero if values less than 16.

```
public class HexTwoChars
{
    static public void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int values[] = { 1, 100, 10000 };
        for (int v: values) 
          System.out.println( String.format("%02x", v % 256 ));
    }
}
```

Running this program prints

```
01
64
10
```